# Powershell check if service is running and log to file

Tags: powershell

So i have 2 variables
one include 4 services
service 1
service 2
service 3
service 4

second variable include all services which are running on computer

```
$servicesall = (Get-service | Group-Object -Property Name).Name
```

$servicestocheck = Get-Content

i want to log to file info like Service 1 is running, Service 2 is not running

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but if you store the services you need in a text file you can do the following:

```
$services = Get-Content "C:\ServiceList.txt"
$statusReport = Get-Service -Name $services | Select-Object Name, Status
$statusReport | Out-File -path "c:\logfile.log"
```

Result:

```
Name     Status
----     ------
spooler Running
winrm   Stopped
wsearch Running
```

The name parameter in `Get-Service -Name $services` accepts an array of strings, which is why you don't need to do any sort of 'foreach' loop.

Comment: I have in file for example  vds, VSS, W32Time, abc, bcd and i want to log vds exist, VSS exist, W32Time exist, abc doesnt exist, bcd doesnt exist

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best way to do this, but here you have something to work with:

```
$services = (
    "vds",
    "VSS",
    "W32Time",
    "abc",
    "bcd"
)

foreach ($item in $services) {
    $service = Get-Service -Name $item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($service) {
        $exist = $true
    } else {
        $exist = $false
        $service = @{
            status = "nope"
            Name = $item
        }
    }

    $service | select Status, Name, @{Name="Exist"; Expression={$exist}}
}
```

Result:

```
Status Name    Exist
 ------ ----    -----
Stopped vds      True
Stopped VSS      True
Running W32Time  True
   nope abc     False
   nope bcd     False
```